# Django admin interface filter from another table linked with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have given two tables and its models.

```
mysql> SELECT gid, sk, source from datagen_gidskmap limit 10;
+-----+------+----------+
| gid | sk   | source   |
+-----+------+----------+
|   1 | 3829 | smsarena |
|   2 | 623  | smsarena |
|   3 | 1308 | smsarena |
|   4 | 1747 | smsarena |
|   5 | 1827 | smsarena |
|   6 | 1218 | smsarena |
|   7 | 2957 | smsarena |
|   8 | 3468 | smsarena |
|   9 | 2580 | smsarena |
|  10 | 2579 | smsarena |
+-----+------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

class GidSkMap(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sk  = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.gid

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("sk", "source")
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT id, gid_id, nm from datagen_crawlmeta limit 10;
+----+--------+----------------------------+
| id | gid_id | nm                         |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|  1 |      1 | votes                      |
|  2 |      1 | performance_rating         |
|  3 |      1 | title                      |
|  4 |      1 | specs__Sound__Loudspeaker  |
|  5 |      1 | specs__Sound__3.5mm jack   |
|  6 |      1 | specs__Sound__Alert types  |
|  7 |      1 | specs__Sound__unknown0     |
|  8 |      1 | specs__Features__Java      |
|  9 |      1 | specs__Features__Messaging |
| 10 |      1 | specs__Features__Colors    |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

class CrawlMeta(models.Model):
    gid = models.ForeignKey(GidSkMap)
    nm = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    val = models.TextField()
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.gid

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("gid", "nm")
```

While viewing the CrawlMeta model in the django admin interface,
I would like to have a filter based on "source"(Eg: smsarena) which can be accessed
via gid (which is a foriegn key in CrawlMeta and primary_key in GidSkMap).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list_filter accepts queryset API style field lookups. in this case you would use:

```
class YourAdmin:
    list_filter = ["gid__source", ... ]
    list_display = ["gid_source", ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It works. Is there a way to show the source column in the table? I added by using `short_description` in the model. But it doesn't allow sorting on source.

Comment: you should be able to add "gid__source" to `list_display` and have it auto sortable.